# Can ξ exist in open interval?

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals

The Second Mean Value Theorem we usually know is : $f(x)$ is *Riemann integrable* in closed interval $[a,b]$ and $g(x)$ is monotonic, thus $\exists$ $\xi \in [a,b]$, such that,
$$\int^{b}_{a} f\left( x\right)  g\left( x\right)  \mathrm{d} x=g\left( a\right)  \int^{\xi }_{a} f\left( x\right)  \mathrm{d} x+g\left( b\right)  \int^{b}_{\xi } f\left( x\right)  \mathrm{d} x $$
The $\xi$ here can not always be found in $(a,b)$, because it is found by Mean Value Theorem, so it might be equal to $a$ or $b$.

But when I strengthen the condition, let $f(x)$ continuous, $g(x)$ monotonic and and derivable, and derivative function $g'(x)$ is riemann integrable(Obviously it is a very strong condition). I will give a another proof.

Set $F\left( x\right)  =\int^{x}_{a} f\left( t\right)  \mathrm{d} t$, i.e. $F(x)$ is continuous and $F(a) = 0$. Because $f(x)$ is continuous, $F(x)$ is a primitive function of $f(x)$. I use intergration by parts:
$$\int^{b}_{a} f\left( x\right)  g\left( x\right)  \mathrm{d} x=F\left( x\right)  g\left( x\right)  |^{b}_{a}-\int^{b}_{a} F\left( x\right)  g^{\prime }\left( x\right)  \mathrm{d} x $$
The first term on the right-hand side of the above equation $$F\left( x\right)  g\left( x\right)  |^{b}_{a}=F\left( b\right)  g\left( b\right)  =g\left( b\right)  \int^{b}_{a} f\left( x\right)  \mathrm{d} x,$$
about the second term, because $g(x)$ is monotonic, $g'(x)$ keeps the definite sign. According to The First Mean Value Theorem, $\exists$ $\xi \in (a,b)$ , such that.
$$\int^{b}_{a} F\left( x\right)  g^{\prime }\left( x\right)  \mathrm{d} x=F\left( \xi \right)  \int^{b}_{a} g^{\prime }\left( x\right)  \mathrm{d} x=[g\left( b\right)  -g\left( a\right)  ]\int^{\xi }_{a} f\left( x\right)  \mathrm{d} x.$$
then$$\int^{b}_{a} f\left( x\right)  g\left( x\right)  \mathrm{d} x=g\left( b\right)  \int^{b}_{a} f\left( x\right)  \mathrm{d} x-[g\left( b\right)  -g\left( a\right)  ]\int^{\xi }_{a} f\left( x\right)  \mathrm{d} x \\=g\left( a\right)  \int^{\xi }_{a} f\left( x\right)  \mathrm{d} x+g\left( b\right)  \int^{b}_{\xi } f\left( x\right)  dx.$$
We can make it clear that $\xi$ here can always be found in $(a,b)$. This is a strengthening of The First Mean Value Theorem. So it seems that whether the eligible $\xi$ certainly exists within the open interval depends on $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

My question is : What $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ can make $\xi$ always be found in the open interval? Conversely, if $\xi$ can be found within $(a,b)$, what character should $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be?

I mean that I am seeking a sufficient and necessary condition.

I would appreciate any answers and ideas.